# Service Fabric Actor Lifecycle during application upgrade

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I couldn't find information on what happens with a service fabric actor during upgrade of the application and deploying a new code package for that actor.

There is some saved state that I want to modify for each actor, but I'm not sure what happens during the upgrade - is there some method that is always called, that i can use like an upgrade hook?

Answer (score 1):

An ActorService is an implementation of a StatefulServiceBase (same base from a StatefulService), so the same [lifecycle of a stateful service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle) applies to the actor service.

ActorService upgrade works exactly the same way as an StatefulService, it also has a [Replica Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-replica-lifecycle), when the primary replica is upgraded, a secondary is promoted to primary and the primary is demoted to secondary, this happens in the event `OnChangeRoleAsync` and you can override it in the ActorService to handle special cases.

Comment: I have created a [post](https://olegkarasik.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/service-fabric-handbook/#reliable-services-stateful-service-life-cycle) with the detailed explanation of Stateful Service life-cycle (unfortunately current documentation is slightly out-of-date - see [issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1268) for details). Hope this can be a useful reference.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for referencing it.